# Any databases that allow you to specify optimized data structure versions of your tables

Tags: database, optimization, design-patterns

I know Redis allows you to store complex data structures in an optimized way. But I'm wondering if there are any databases or design patterns out there that allow you to specify optimized versions of chunks of your database.

For example, to do quick lookups of things by text, you have to resort to [solr](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#searching-objects) for searching, which is its own database specifically for optimizing looking through strings.

Another example is if you want to return an easy to navigate roles object for the user, you might want it like this:

```
var user = { roles: { admin: true, principal: true, ... } }
```

But in the database you probably have a `roles` table and a `users` table, so you do a join and fetch them back and eventually build up that data structure manually in your code.

The question is, is there anything out there that allows you to specify the data structure / form of your data directly in the database, for faster lookups. Databases allow you to have indexes which is a primitive solution. Wondering if there are more complex examples. For example, a great way to check if an item has a tag is to do:

```
user.tags[tagName]
```

That would mean your tags are like this:

```
{ tagA: true, tagB: true, ... }
```

But you probably get them from the database like this:

```
[ { name: tagA }, { name: tagB } ]
```

So wondering if there is a way to tell the database, create an "optimized version" of the dataset in this "x" format, rather than having to manually do this in the application layer. Wondering if there are any tools or design patterns around this.

Comment: do you mean [materialized views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL))?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to optimize a specific data structure, you can always optimize it yourself on a low-level database, something as simple as SQLite, or as complex as PostgreSQL, and make it easy to use by adding a database object handling layer. If you don't want to optimize it yourself. In my experience the Django web framework did a pretty good job making it easy to store and receive objects in a RMDB without limiting me access from tinkering within the database itself.

With this solution you can use the RMDB *like* an OODB with a bit of extra design needed in your structures (which, by the sounds of it, you already have). And still allows you to choose an optimized DB storage engine for your specific structure/access requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned a **key-val** store (okay, in case of **Redis** a *data structure store*),
and relational database management systems that enforce a rigid data scheme.

If I understood your question correctly you need something in between - not as low-level as **redis** and not as restrictive as a rdbms

I’d suggest giving a chance to a [document-oriented store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database)

> A document-oriented database, or document store, is a computer program
>   designed for storing, retrieving and managing document-oriented
>   information, also known as semi-structured data.

Here are you examples translated into [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/)

> MongoDB is an open-source, document database designed for ease of
>   development and scaling

#### here's the first one

```
var user = { roles: { admin: true, principal: true, ... } }

> db.createCollection('user');
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.user.insert({roles: ['admin', 'principal']})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.user.insert({roles: ['admin']})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.user.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a8f1ae9442b9e31f71b156c"), "roles" : [ "admin", "principal" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a8f1c46442b9e31f71b156d"), "roles" : [ "admin" ] }
```

You see? Looks quite straightforward

#### the second one

```
{ tagA: true, tagB: true, ... }
```

Using the previous example (for *tags* or whatever else it would work similarly)

```
> db.user.find({roles: {$in: ['principal']}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a8f1ae9442b9e31f71b156c"), "roles" : [ "admin", "principal" ] }
```

You can even create an index on *roles*!

```
> db.user.ensureIndex({roles: 1})

> db.user.find({roles: {$in: ['principal']}}).explain()
...
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "roles" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "roles_1",
...
```

Besides a bunch of flexible CRUD operations there’s also a lot bells & whistles like [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) that allows handling your data right on the spot.

There’s a bunch of other document-oriented solutions like that having its own pros/cons depending on data *durability* / *performance* / *scaling* requirements of your app

But in any case it's not a silver bullet and a mixed approach like you described i.e. using a **rdbms** + **full-text search system** or some in-memory k/v counters like **memcached**/**redis** for specific tasks might be the best way to go

Answer (score 0):

Object Databases (OODBs) can store objects they way you describe.  One downside is that they are usually highly coupled to one or two programming languages and are not suitable for running reports or exporting to other systems.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object_database_management_systems

Document databases (or NoSQL) store a language-neutral representation of your object hierarchy (usually JSON).  The schema is sometimes defined before you write your data, but more often the schema is defined by your queries (schema-on-read paradigm). They can store relationships between data, but they are harder to query for analytical purposes.  (i.e. how do you find out which objects/documents have the most tags in common?)

Relational databases store sets of data that can combined in different ways at query time.  The schema is generally defined before you store data (schema-on-write).  Language specific Object-Relational-Mappers (ORMS) are used to ease the storage and retrieval of objects between a programming language and relational sets.

Some traditional relational databases can store hierarchical structure in JSON or XML columns.  This provides some of the benefit of schema-on-read document databases (noSQL).  You can use XPath or special JSON expressions to query the structure stored in the column.

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` int(ii) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `tags` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

SELECT * FROM `book` 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tags, '["JavaScript"]');
```

These descriptions are broad generalizations and you can find examples of different features and techniques in products referred to by one of these labels.  For example, not all noSQL databases are schema-on-read:  Solr and Cassandra require schemas defined ahead of writes.